# vimscript rgb/rgba regex

Tags: regex, vim, colors

I'm trying to learn vimscript, so I got the idea of making rgb(a) <-> hex color converter inside vim. I'm currently trying to get it working for css, I already made the part that parses the color (returns "#123456" "rgb(120,120,120)" etc.) and determines if its hex (starting with "#"), now I'm trying to detect proper rgb/rgba colors.

The problem is I'm unable to figure out the regex for it, I made one at https://regex101.com/

I used `^rgba?\(\d+,\d+,\d+\)` to match both rgb and rgba with digits inside brackets (with gm flags). On the site it works fine, I used this to search in:

```
rgb(10,10,10)
rgba(1,150,20)
rgba(1,2,3)
rgb(12,34,56)
rgba(1,1,1)
rgba(1,150,20)
rgb
rgba
rgb()
rgba()
```

After some google searching I found out that vim uses its own syntax, I searched in the vim docs and changed the pattern to `^rgba\?\(\d\+,\d\+,\d\+\)`. But still no luck.

Sample vimscript code:

```
let color="rgba(10,10,10)"
let s:match = match(color, "^rgba\?\(\d\+,\d\+,\d\+\)")
echom s:match
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction? Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

**Update**

I wasn't able to make it work with whitespaces ("\s" and " ") didn't seem to work, so I just removed all of them with `let color = substitute(color, '\s', '', 'g')`.

Anyways, I'm using what Dan Lowe suggested: `\v^rgba?\(\d+,\d+,\d+\)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
match(color, '\v^rgba?\(\d+,\d+,\d+\)')
```

It's always a good idea to specify the match mode for these things, because otherwise the behavior can be influenced by whether you are using magic mode.

Here I have used `\v` to specify "very magic" mode. That is defined as:

> Use of `\v` means that in the pattern after it all ASCII characters except
>   `0`-`9`, `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z` and `_` have a special meaning.  "very magic"

It's closer to what you are probably used to in other languages (Python, Perl, Ruby, etc). Notice that you don't need to backslash-quote nearly as much, this looks more like a regex from any common language.

It also makes tools such as regex101 more useful in this case. You probably noticed that regex101 has a few flavors, but vim isn't one of them. If you use very magic mode, the pcre flavor will (mostly) work for vim regex.

Comment: Great, that worked! I've read about the "very magic" mode, but someone said it may act weird. Thanks a lot :)